# Music management Software

Tags: windows, file-management, music

I need a Software for Windows 10 to organize my audio files.
I want a Software that I can assign keywords or tags to the audio file and later to search the files based on these tags or keywords. It is good if I can choose multiples tags to refine the search.

Comment: If this is commercial music, there are apps which will do that for you automatically.

Comment: Take a look at MediaMonkey.